# Given 2 sorted files - delete all words found in another

Tags: linux, diff

On Linux I have two text files with russian UTF8 words sorted with `sort -u` (actually I used `:%sort u` in Vim, it produces same results).

One of the files `dict.txt` contains around 700000 words of my custom dictionary. Another file `bad-words.txt` contains often mistyped words.

I'd like to remove all words found in `bad-words.txt` from `dict.txt`.

I know that a perl script using a hash could do that, but I'm after a Unix one liner.

Ist there please a Unix command (maybe something using `diff`?) to perform this task? And I hope `diff` won't be confused by the large number of lines - because "Beyond compare" program on Windows is...

Answer (score 3):

comm will do this.

`comm -3 dict badwords`

or to sort on the fly:

`comm -3 <(sort dict-input) <(badwords)`

Comment: Unfortunately it complains `comm: file 1 is not in sorted order` (despite me presorting it) and produces strange 2-columns output...

Comment: `comm` expects the file to be sorted in ASCIIbetical order, e.g. `LANG=C sort`.

Comment: @grawity: That advice saved my day :) Thanks!